# Is it recommended to add external ESD protection to devices that have internal ESD protection?

Tags: protection, esd

I have to design a system composed of a main PCB and enclosure (with multiple interfaces - UART, RS-232, SPI, I2C, GPIO) and an external interface board without enclosure (with only connectors for external devices/sensors). The two are connected via a 64-pin ribbon cable.

I would like to ensure ESD protection and I was thinking of putting ESD protection devices on the external board. However, some of the circuits located on the main PCB (such as [the RS-232 transceiver](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn65c23243) or [I2C-SPI bridge](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC18IS602B.pdf)) already integrate ESD protection.

So, is it really necessary to add external ESD protection in this case?

Comment: What ESD level are you considering? What ESD do your components meet?

Comment: It depends.  A human finger body model is used to rate ESD using an RC network of 100R+100pF AFAIRecall, Cable capacitance is 100pF/m max might night achieve this high V unless dragged across a nylon carpet or near a very high E field transient.  ESD consists of 2 stages  of 10k + a pair of rail diode clamps into CMOS high Z.  You must define your expected EMI sources to determine if augmented protection is needed.  e.g. indoors near welders our outdoors near lightning.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The system will be placed outdoor in a large metal enclosure.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know what ESD protection level is required. All I know is that the system will be placed outdoor in a large metal enclosure.

Comment: Then you might also need to consider lightning protection. I can't tell you what your design requirements are. You have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: Yes I think the terminal is protected, but nothing said about cable Rx antenna environment. possible ok. Then there Tempest qualified for security and EMP for hopefully unlikely events yet possible